# How to create unique branches in repos within repos

Tags: git, github

I have several repos within repos. 
In repo3 I want to create several branches. When I move back a repo, i.e. in repo2, and do `git branch`, it shows me all the branches present in both repo2 and repo3. But what I want is to be able to create branches unique to their repos and and these branches shouldn't show up in repo2.

This diagram shows how I want:

```
   repo1/ repo2/ repo3 
            |      |
            |      |
            |      |_ _ _branchX, branchY, branchZ, branchK
            |
            |
          branchA, branchB, branchC
```

Comment: How many actual `.git` files do you have here?

Comment: I have .git file only in repo1.

Comment: Look into using Git submodules.  This would work as follows: Inside `repo2`, there would be a branch representing the submodule `repo3`.  Inside `repo3`, you would then see all of its branches.

Comment: thanks for information on submodule. This is how I did finally:  I `git init` in each repo. Then I created new branches respective to that repo. When I moved a repo back and did `git branch`, it only showed branches present within that current repo.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this is not solved yet. Although it is possible to do gitinit in each repo, but this will give too many errors while pushing to github. Basically you have to add origins like this: `git remote add origin ssh://git@example.com:1234/myRepo.git` for each repo within repo. I'm now looking into git submodules suggestion.

Comment: Submodules sound like a good fit for the behavior you want.  By the way, many frown upon submodules, so really the best answer might be to change your design so you don't even need them.

Comment: Git doesn't "do" repos-within-repos. The nearest thing is *submodules*, but those are multiple *independent* repos.  Well, sort-of-independent: a repo that refers to another repo as a "submodule" depends on that other repo existing, and having some specific commit (by hash ID). So if you ever remove the target of the submodule, the referring repo (the one with the submodule) is SOL. Up the creek without a paddle. Screwed, boned, had its mellow harshed...

Answer (score 0):

> This is how I did finally: I `git init` in each repo. Then I created new branches respective to that repo. When I moved a repo back and did `git branch`, it only showed branches present within that current repo.

Yes, but it also registered a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) for the nested repo... without registering the nested repo remote url.
So when `repo2` will make new commits and push them, `repo1` will register the new repo2 SHA1 (gitlink), but won't know where that SHA1 is coming from (remote repo url).
Cloning again `repo1` will result in an empty `repo2` (and no `repo3`)

The proper way to initialize `repo1` is by having `repo2` and `repo3` initialized separately, that is:

```
cd /path/to/repo2
git submodule add -- /url/repo3
git add .
git commit -m "Add repo3 as submodule"
git push

cd /path/to/repo1
git submodule add -- /url/repo2
git add .
git commit -m "Add repo2 as submodule"
git push
```

With that setting, a `git branch` done in `repo1`, `2` or `3` will only show the branches for the current repo.